# How to change the xsl variable value inside For Each Loop

Tags: xslt

I have a below piece of code

```
          <xsl:when test="$fldKey = 'partyAddresses'">
                
                <xsl:variable name="isMaskingRequired" select="'false'"/>
                
                <xsl:for-each select="$rootDocument/externalEnrichment/SensitiveData/">
                    <xsl:if test="field/text()[. = $fldKey]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'*****'"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="isMaskingRequired" select="'true'"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                
                <xsl:if test="$isMaskingRequired = 'false'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="writePartyAddresses"/>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:when>
```

I want to call writePartyAddresses template only when isMaskingRequired is set to false.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:variable name="isMaskingRequired" select="'false'"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="isMaskingRequired">false</xsl:variable>
```

When you use select, whatever you select has to exist in the current node.

Comment: Still the value of variable 'isMaskingRequired' is not getting changed to 'true'.

Comment: The value of isMaskingRequired will not change outside of the context of the for-reach. It's hard to tell without seeing the xml, but perhaps you should be checking SensitiveData via count ().

Comment: Actually i have solved this problem by checking the xpath only. Here loop is not required.
This is resolved. Thanks guys for your time.